# GT Metrix show Errors even when BROWSER CACHE is active?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, litespeed

1-Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy
There are lots of .mp4/woff/woff2/png files that have no CACHE TTL or just 1week ttl
https://prnt.sc/AhbiAm19HjzU
but in my .htaccess file I see these : A315576000 means 180 days to expire

```
### marker BROWSER CACHE start ###
```

#### marker BROWSER CACHE start

ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/pdf A315576000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A315576000
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon A315576000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A315576000

ExpiresByType image/jpg A315576000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A315576000
ExpiresByType image/png A315576000
ExpiresByType image/gif A315576000
ExpiresByType image/webp A315576000

ExpiresByType video/ogg A315576000
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A315576000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A315576000
ExpiresByType video/webm A315576000

ExpiresByType text/css A315576000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A315576000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A315576000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A315576000

ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A315576000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A315576000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A315576000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A315576000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A315576000
ExpiresByType font/ttf A315576000
ExpiresByType font/otf A315576000
ExpiresByType font/woff A315576000
ExpiresByType font/woff2 A315576000

### marker BROWSER CACHE end ###

**But GTmetrix could not detect that !**

2-remove unused Java Scripts / this file belongs to Litespeed chache plugin and was repated 6 times on Iteams in Gtmetrix :
*Use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance
*Reduce unused JavaScript
*Avoid long main-thread tasks
*Reduce JavaScript execution time
*Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern browsers
please see the images :
https://prnt.sc/bwMd6iLEZqo0
https://prnt.sc/DxIfdR9-gln2
Is there any suggestion to solve that ?

3-Based on Litespeed dos not support Perload the font yeat , I found the code for that and suould put in htaccess file

Header add Link "</wp-content/themes/betheme/fonts/fontawesome/fa-solid-900.woff2>; rel=preload; as=font; crossorigin=anonymous"
Header add Link "</wp-content/themes/betheme/fonts/mfn/icons.woff?31690507>; rel=preload; as=font; crossorigin=anonymous"

but it’s not working and still get error of Avoid chaining critical requests
Can you please tell me or guid me what should I do for this one ?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Browser Cache**

If you are using OpenLiteSpeed, please custom the Expired value, e.g. A315576000 from the LiteSpeed web admin > Server Configuration > General > Expires Settings because OLS only read rewrite rules from the .htaccess file, the rest rules will be ignored.

**Unused Java Scripts**

What LSCache did is to minify/combine the JS files that your site has, but it is actually not originally from LSCache. To verify it, you can deactivate the LSCache and check it on GTMetrix again.

**Font Preload**

Although the Font Preload is on the to-do, the server support server push feature a long time ago.
Check this forum https://wordpress.org/support/topic/use-preload-for-fonts/